# How to yum downgrade to a specific version of packet like jdk?

Tags: centos, yum, openjdk

I know it's
sudo yum downgrade <package_name>-<version_info>

but always can't find the packet.

for example

```
sudo yum --showduplicates list java-1.7.0-openjdk
Installed Packages
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.261-2.6.22.1.el6_10                                     @C6.10-updates
Available Packages
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.181-2.6.14.10.el6                                       C6.10-base    
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.191-2.6.15.4.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.201-2.6.16.0.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.211-2.6.17.1.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.221-2.6.18.0.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.231-2.6.19.1.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.231-2.6.19.2.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.241-2.6.20.0.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.251-2.6.21.0.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates 
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64                                     1:1.7.0.261-2.6.22.1.el6_10                                     C6.10-updates
```

1:1.7.0.201-2.6.16.0.el6_10 is the version i want

then I issue

```
sudo yum downgrade java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64-1:1.7.0.201-2.6.16.0.el6_10

No package java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64-1:1.7.0.201-2.6.16.0.el6_10 available.
Nothing to do
```

I tried

```
sudo yum downgrade java-1.7.0-openjdk-1:1.7.0.201-2.6.16.0.el6_10       

No package java-1.7.0-openjdk-1:1.7.0.201-2.6.16.0.el6_10 available.
Nothing to do
```

Can anyone help???

Comment: ? How about `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.201-2.6.16.0.el6_10` ......... or 'yum install --downloadonly ....' and --force install with rpm ?